# Change GitHub repository on Overleaf?

Tags: overleaf, git

I linked an Overleaf project to GitHub. Then I changed the name of the repository on GitHub. How does one change or unlink an Overleaf project from GitHub once it's been linked?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is not LaTeX-related, see also https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8045/support-questions-about-overleaf-off-topic.

Comment: Fair enough. We have clear answer below, which I hope is helpful to others facing a similar issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm on support staff at Overleaf. It is not possible to change the Github repository a project is linked to after the link is made - sorry for the inconvenience. If you need to do this, you could copy the project on Overleaf and link the copy to a new repo, or start a new project from the new Github repo. In either case, the History of changes on Overleaf would start from scratch.

Hope this is useful. We're available at support@overleaf.com for any questions you have.

Comment: Oh wow that's really a limiting issue.

Comment: Sad story, I renamed my repository and I really hope I can just relink the GitHub repo.